# Where to add validation data annotation attribute while using Viewmodel whose items are coming from different model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have linking tables that have multiple foreign keys in SQL Server. I am using a view model to create, edit, delete in EF database-first so that I can use validation attributes in case of database changes. I have used data annotation but mapped id columns are not being validated.

Now, in this situation, where to add a validation attribute that I can get proper response for every column while posting it?

I won't use validation and annotation attributes in generated models from database. Then where to add them and what else need to do?

Please see these model class generated from database and the view model also.

```
public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.Resumes = new HashSet<Resume>();
        this.StudentSkills = new HashSet<StudentSkill>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ResumeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentSkill> StudentSkills { get; set; }
}

public partial class Skill
{
    public Skill()
    {
        this.StudentSkills = new HashSet<StudentSkill>();
    }

    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentSkill> StudentSkills { get; set; }
}

public partial class StudentSkill
{
    public int StudentSkillsId { get; set; }
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

public partial class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public partial class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public partial class Resume
{
    public System.Guid ResumeId { get; set; }
    public string ResumeName { get; set; }
    public string ResumeExtention { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

View model class:

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="You must enter your name")]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a country")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a country")]
    public IEnumerable<Country> Country { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a city")]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a city")]
    public IEnumerable<City> City { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose at least one skill")]
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose at least one skill")]
    public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must upload your resume")]
    public List<Resume> Resumes { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter Birth Date")]

    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought here.
Maybe the following article can give an idea it is from Microsoft's forum, so give it a glance: 
https://forums.asp.net/t/1976800.aspx?Where+To+put+Data+Annotation+Validation

It says that you have you will have to map between the Mode and the ViewModel.

If you find something out, or the above article helped you out, write back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks fine for me. In your controller HttpPost method you need in the first lines do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel mymodel){
if (!ModelState.IsValid){
return View(mymodel);
}
else {    
//do business logic
return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
     }
}
```

But this validation will never check if the id is a valid id exists in the db or do any validation on the business domain, you must implement those for yourself.

Comment: Its working for city and countries, thank you for that! But I need to add some more logic for other items. @jojess

Comment: What is it exactly that you wish to accomplish and where do you fail?
As @vasilisdmr wrote you also need to map your ViewModels to the EF POCO classes, I use AutoMapper for that.

Comment: Got any news on your issue?

Comment: @vasilisdmr not yet! I have added validation in the viewmodel class, some are working, but some are still not being affected by that, like files and dateOfBirth

Comment: Did you try out my suggestion from the original comment?

Comment: Please define "not working". What do you want to exactly acomplish?

Comment: @vasilisdmr yes!

Comment: @vasilisdmr though your solution didn't worked fully, i'm accepting your ans. because it helped me.

Comment: @SagarFi to which answer are you referring to?

Comment: @vasilisdmr the solution you provided as answer